# How to restrict the height of an image in a table cell to the same as the adjacent cell, without JavaScript?

Tags: html, css

How can I make the image in the red box be no taller than the table to its right?

It is a high-resolution image that is downscaled using `max-width: 100%` on the image.

[image]

I've tried `display: flex` on `#featured` and `display: block` on `#featured img` but I must be missing something.

The desired behaviour is to set the image's height the same as `#condition` and center the image horizontally if it doesn't fill the width.

I want the image to print out on to physical paper by default (without the user changing printer settings), so using a `background-image` is out of the question.

The platform I am targeting has no support for JavaScript - I can only use HTML & CSS. I know it is sacrilege, but this particular platform has good support for table layouts and poor support for typical modern `<div>` layouts - so I'd prefer to keep it as a nested table layout.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}

#featured {
  padding: 2% 1% 2% 2%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 47%;
}

#featured img {
  border: 0.5em solid red;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#condition {
  padding: 2% 2% 2% 1%;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 47%;
}

#condition table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#condition td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#product {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>

    <td id="featured">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://i.imgur.com/sNc50nG_d.webp?maxwidth=1520&fidelity=grand">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/sNc50nG_d.webp?maxwidth=1520&fidelity=grand" alt="">
      </a>
    </td>

    <td id="condition">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Condition</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Overall</td>
          <td>Excellent</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Box</td>
          <td>Excellent</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Game</td>
          <td>Excellent</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td id="product" colspan="2">{Product ID}</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cjtpk1mr/)

Comment: your problem may be that the table on the right is not filling the space so you might be confused about what is going on, but the image is staying in the td. The table on the right is smaller than the TD that it is in.

Comment: This isn't a true answer, but have you tried adding `float: left; box-sizing: border-box;`  to the `#featured` css? It's definitely not perfect or ideal, but in an *oddball* situation with the platform you are using, it seems like it might get you closer to what you want.

Comment: @Sean The inner `<table>` under `condition` is, yes - but the outermost `<table>` is not.

Comment: I think the easiest approach is to replace the outer single-row `<table>` with a single `<div>` with `display: flex;` and `align-items: stretch`. If there's more markup that we're not seeing then you really should say-so, as I assumed the HTML you posted is literally what you're working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the image in an absolutely-positioned div and set its height to 100%.

Note that I'm using classes instead of IDs. CSS should be reusable when possible, and IDs must be unique in a document.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.featured {
  width: 47%;
  position: relative;
}

.featured-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.featured-img img {
  height: calc(100% - 1em);
  border: 0.5em solid red;
}

#condition {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 47%;
}

#condition table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#condition td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#product {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>

    <td class="featured">
      <div class="featured-img">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://i.imgur.com/sNc50nG_d.webp?maxwidth=1520&fidelity=grand">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/sNc50nG_d.webp?maxwidth=1520&fidelity=grand">
        </a>
      </div>
    </td>

    <td id="condition">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Condition</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Overall</td>
          <td>Excellent</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Box</td>
          <td>Excellent</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Game</td>
          <td>Excellent</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td id="product" colspan="2">{Product ID}</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeming as you won't dispense with the outer `<table>`, I thusly present the nuclear option...

```css
table#outer,
table#outer>tbody {
  display: contents;
}

table#outer>tbody>tr:first-child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

table#outer>tbody>tr>td#featured {
  display: contents;
}

table#outer>tbody>tr>td#featured>a {
  display: block;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 5;
  position: relative;
}

table#outer>tbody>tr>td#featured>a>img {
  /*
    border: 0.5em solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    flex-basis: 50%;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 5;
*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /*  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;*/
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

table#outer>tbody>tr>td#condition {
  display: block;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

td#condition>table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}

#condition>table td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

table#outer>tbody>tr:nth-child(2) {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

table#outer>tbody>tr:nth-child(2)>td#product {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table id="outer">
  <tr>

    <td id="featured">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://i.imgur.com/sNc50nG_d.webp?maxwidth=1520&fidelity=grand">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/sNc50nG_d.webp?maxwidth=1520&fidelity=grand" alt="">
      </a>
    </td>

    <td id="condition">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Condition</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Overall</td>
          <td>Excellent</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Box</td>
          <td>Excellent</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Game</td>
          <td>Excellent</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td id="product" colspan="2">{Product ID}</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: @DannyBeckett I thought I could get it working using only flex layout, but eventually I gave-up and resorted to `position: absolute;` which is essentially the same technique used by @isherwood - which kinda makes all the `display:` overrides here irrelevant.